# Asp Net MVC Dropdownlist Mustache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mustache.js

na minha aplicação quando o usuário clica em incluir realizo duas consultas e cada uma retorna (id e nome), montei um template do mustache, e gostaria de carregar esses dados em dois dropdownlist. a pergunta é como carregar esses dados.

```js
 $(document).on('click', '#btn_incluir', function () {
        
           var btn = $(this);

                if ("#txt_horaI" == "HH:MM") {
                    message: "Campo Hora Incial não pode ser vazio";
                }
                else if ("#txt_horaF" == "HH:MM") {
                    message: "Campo Hora Final não pode ser vazio";
                }
                else {
                    var url = '@Url.Action("RecuperarA", "Operacao")',
                        
                        dadosA = { 
                            carros                          
                        };
                      var url = '@Url.Action("RecuperarP", "Operacao")',
                        dadosB = { 
                        motorista
                        };
                     incluir_linha_produto();
                }
            })
            
            
             function incluir_linha_produto() {

            $('#grid tbody').append(Mustache.render($('#template-produto').html() ));
        }
        
         <script id="template-produto" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="De">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Para">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Cliente">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="Motrista"><option selected="selected" value="">Motorista</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="carro"><option selected="selected" value="">carro</option></select>
            </td>            
            <td>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Tempo">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-warning btn_remover" role="button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
```

Consigo chegar ate dadosA e dadosB depois disso estou perdido. não sei como continuar.

Comment: Mais fácil ganhar na mega sena que aparecer um soberbo pra orientar.

Comment: ai vc olha varias perguntas fechadas, sem nem darem o min de atenção.Ha desculpa aqui se preza muito pela qualidade subjetiva.

Comment: É que não ficou muito claro o que você precisa... Por isso que ninguém orienta... Você precisa recuperar os dados e montar num select isso? Exemplo um combo de motorisa isso?

Comment: Edenilson, como disse, consigo chegar no controller aonde posso ter uma ActionResult ou um JsonResult(obs estou tentando das duas formas pois estou estudando) o que não sei como fazer é carregar os dados num dropdownlist do mustache. aqui

Comment: <select id="Motrista"><option selected="selected" value="">Motorista</option></select>                    como que carrego os dados  vindo daqui por exemplo  public JsonResult RecuperarNN(string DT, string HI, string HF)
        { var ListaA = OperacaoModel.RecuperarListaMotoristaN(DT, HI, HF);
           return Json(ListaA );        
        }

Comment: Eu vou colocar como eu faço aqui, pode ser util, porem não uso ActionResult uso Json

Comment: Mustache seria um Framework tipo Bootstrap isso?

Comment: sim.. eu estava testando das duas formas tanto por Actionresult como por Json.

Answer (score 0):

fiz assim e funcionou.
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_incluir").click(function () {
                var f = {};
                f.url = '@Url.Action("RecuperarNN", "Operacao")';
                f.type = "POST";
                f.dataType = "json";
                f.data = JSON.stringify({ Dt: $('#txt_data').val(), HI: $('#txt_horaI').val(), HF: $('#txt_horaF').val() });
                f.contentType = "aplication/json";
                f.success = function (r) {
                    $("#Aeroi").empty();
                    $("#Aeroi").prepend("option value='' selected='selected'>");
                    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                        $("#Aeri").append('' + r[i].Ae + '');
                    }
                };
                $.ajax(f);
              });

```
    });
```